# gpsd TPV json data has 95% conficence errors (ex: ept, epx, epy ...) How do you use the numbers?

Tags: gps, gpsd

[image]

http://www.catb.org/gpsd/gpsd_json.html

Let's say I get

- `"alt":1343.127`
- `"epv":32.321`

in TPV data.

`epv` is "Estimated vertical error in meters, 95% confidence", so this means, at 95% of chance, the data has 32.321 meters differences in 1343.127(alt) meters from the actual altitude?

Same question goes to other error values such as ept, epx, epy, epd ..

- ept for time
- epx for longitude
- epy for latitude
- epv for altitude
- epd for track (heading)??
- eps for speed
- epc for climb

Answer (score 2):

The error estimates are within a "95% confidence interval" -- There is a 0.95 chance that the actual altitude in your example is between 1310 and 1375 meters.